Implement Custom QWidgets as Popup for a QTimeEdit
QTimeEdit has no 'popup' widget and it's overall design makes it "not nice to use".
Therefore I coded two custom QWidget classes:

class Clock_hourWidget(QWidget): class/object returns/emits first valid hour input
class Clock_minuteWidget(QWidget): class/object returns/emit first valid minute input

And i embedded them into a Custom QTimeEdit:
import math
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTimeEdit, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTime, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Clock_hourWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    return_hour = 15
    first = True

    def __init__(self, hours, callback, parent=None):
        super(Clock_hourWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup)
        self.callback = callback
        self.setFixedSize(150,150)
        self.hours = hours

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.rect().contains(event.localPos().toPoint()):
            self.first = False
            self.return_hour = self.hours
        self.close()

    @property
    def hour(self):
        if self.first:
            result = -1
        else:
            result = self.return_hour
        return result
    
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.callback(self.hour)
        event.accept()


class Clock_minuteWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    return_minutes = 30

    def __init__(self, minutes, callback, parent=None):
        super(Clock_minuteWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Popup)
        self.setFixedSize(150,150)
        self.callback = callback
        self.minutes = minutes

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.rect().contains(event.localPos().toPoint()):
            self.return_minutes = self.minutes
        self.close()

    @property
    def minute(self):
        return self.return_minutes

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.callback(self.minute)
        event.accept()


class CustomTimeEdit(QTimeEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomTimeEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDisplayFormat("HH:mm")
        self.setCalendarPopup(False)
        # calendar_icon = QIcon.fromTheme("calendar")
        # self.setButtonSymbols(calendar_icon)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.open_clock_hourwidget()

    def return_hour(self, hour):
        self.clock_hourwidget = None
        if hour != -1:
            self.hours = hour
            self.minutes = self.time().minute()
            self.setTime(QTime(self.hours, self.minutes))
            self.clock_minutewidget = Clock_minuteWidget(self.minutes, self.clock_finalizer)
            pos = self.mapToGlobal(self.rect().bottomLeft())
            pos = self.adjust_Popup_positioning(pos, self.clock_minutewidget)
            self.clock_minutewidget.move(pos)
            self.clock_minutewidget.show()

    def open_clock_hourwidget(self):
        self.hours = self.time().hour()
        self.clock_hourwidget = Clock_hourWidget(self.hours, self.return_hour)
        pos = self.mapToGlobal(self.rect().bottomLeft())
        pos = self.adjust_Popup_positioning(pos, self.clock_hourwidget)
        self.clock_hourwidget.move(pos)
        self.clock_hourwidget.show()

    def adjust_Popup_positioning(self, pos, widget):
        screen = QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
        screen_geometry = QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen)
        if pos.y() + widget.height() > screen_geometry.height():
            pos = self.mapToGlobal(self.rect().topLeft())
            pos.setY(pos.y() - widget.height())
        if pos.x() < screen_geometry.left():
            pos.setX(screen_geometry.left())
        elif pos.x() + widget.width() > screen_geometry.right():
            pos.setX(screen_geometry.right() - widget.width())
        return pos

    def clock_finalizer(self, minute):
        self.clock_minutewidget = None
        self.setTime(QTime(self.hours, minute))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    time_edit = CustomTimeEdit()
    time_edit.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

I want the popup to behave like the CalendarPopup of QDateEdit (crossed out functionality already in above code snippet):

The popup should open up under the Custom QTimeEdit
If there is not enough space under the Custom QTimeEdit, it should show above the Custom QTimeEdit
If there is not enough space to the right, it should move slightly to the left and vice versa
Most importantly and seemingly undoable: if the user clicks outside the popup OR if the popup (maybe the whole application) looses focus (by pressing windows key or alt-tab for example): the popup closes.
The button of Custom QTimeEdit should look and behave like the CalendarPopup Button of QDateEdit/QDateTimeEdit (setCalendarPopup(True)): Looks should change depending on used style and platform

I can provide full code if needed but for simplicity reasons i tried to cut it down as much as possible.

You should set the Qt.Popup window flag for the popup widget. You can check the geometry using QScreen. If you want further help, please provide a complete [mre] (it doesn't require the painting part, just ensure it's runnable and the popup is shown).

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Other than inheriting QDateTimeEdit and setting .setCalendarPopup(True) (which generates the correct button) and overloading it, I haven't had any ideas. Unfortunately, setting .setDisplayFormat("HH:mm") "converts" this button back again. A short overview of how it can/should be solved would (probably) be enough.

QTimeEdit and QDateEdit are fundamentally dummy classes: they do not provide any specific difference in behavior than QDateTimeEdit from which they inherit, and, in fact, it's enough to set a proper displayFormat() on QDateTimeEdit to get the same results.
Now, what QDateTimeEdit does is to partially behave similarly to an editable QComboBox whenever the calendarPopup property is True and it's actually showing a date Section (either one of day, month or year).
This is achieved (other than in mouse handlers) in the paintEvent(): if the popup shouldn't be shown (calendarPopup is False or no date section is present in displayFormat()), it just calls the basic paintEvent() of QAbstractSpinBox, which internally creates a QStyleOptionSpinBox instance, calls the virtual initStyleOption() (which is that of QDateTimeEdit, but in that case would be identical since no date section is shown) and finally uses the widget's style drawComplexControl() function with it.
If, otherwise, the popup may be shown, it uses QStyle features to show itself like an editable combo box by adding some subControls specific to it: the combo frame, its edit field and, most importantly, the arrow.
Therefore, in order to force the painting of the arrow, we need to mimic that same behavior. Note that since the arrow may be shown differently depending on the mouse over state, we need to ensure that the option activeSubControls are also consistent, which is achieved by forcing mouse tracking and checking the position in mouseMoveEvent() and enter/leave events.
Be aware that the following code also installs an event filter on the inner line edit in order to consistently check if the mouse leaves or enters it: the line edit is a child widget, so entering it doesn't result in a Leave event for the parent.
class CustomTimeEdit(QTimeEdit):
    clock_hourwidget = clock_minutewidget = None
    _onArrow = False
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomTimeEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setDisplayFormat("HH:mm")
        self.setCalendarPopup(False)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.lineEdit().installEventFilter(self)

    ...
    def _setOnArrow(self, onArrow):
        if self._onArrow != onArrow:
            self._onArrow = onArrow
            self.update()

    def _checkOnArrow(self, pos):
        style = self.style()
        opt = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        arrowRect = style.subControlRect(style.CC_ComboBox, opt, 
            style.SC_ComboBoxArrow, self)
        self._setOnArrow(arrowRect.contains(pos))

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not event.buttons():
            self._checkOnArrow(event.pos())
        else:
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super().enterEvent(event)
        self._checkOnArrow(self.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos()))

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super().leaveEvent(event)
        self._setOnArrow(False)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == event.Enter:
            self._setOnArrow(False)
        elif event.type() == event.Leave:
            self._checkOnArrow(self.mapFromGlobal(QCursor.pos()))
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)            

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        opt = QStyleOptionSpinBox()
        QAbstractSpinBox.initStyleOption(self, opt)
        style = self.style()

        opt.subControls = (
            style.SC_ComboBoxFrame | style.SC_ComboBoxEditField
            | style.SC_ComboBoxArrow
        )
        if self.clock_hourwidget or self.clock_minutewidget:
            opt.state |= style.State_Sunken
        else:
            opt.state &= ~style.State_Sunken
        optCombo = QStyleOptionComboBox()
        optCombo.initFrom(self)
        optCombo.editable = True
        optCombo.frame = opt.frame
        optCombo.subControls = opt.subControls
        optCombo.state = opt.state

        if self._onArrow:
            optCombo.activeSubControls = style.SC_ComboBoxArrow

        qp = QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawComplexControl(
            style.CC_ComboBox, optCombo, qp, self)

Note that QDesktopWidget has been declared obsolete for some time now, and QScreen should always be preferred instead. Also, calling the desktop widget's cursor() to get its position is pointless (since it's the same as the static QCursor.pos()), and the geometry computation should be more careful (other than simpler). For instance:
...
    def open_clock_hourwidget(self):
        self.hours = self.time().hour()
        self.clock_hourwidget = Clock_hourWidget(self.hours, self.return_hour)
        self.adjustPopup(self.clock_hourwidget)

    def adjustPopup(self, widget):
        pos = self.mapToGlobal(self.rect().bottomLeft())
        geo = widget.geometry()
        geo.moveTopLeft(pos)
        screen = (QApplication.screenAt(pos) or self.screen()).geometry()
        if geo.right() > screen.right():
            geo.moveRight(screen.right())
        if geo.x() < screen.x():
            geo.moveLeft(screen.left())
        if geo.bottom() > screen.bottom():
            geo.moveBottom(screen.bottom())
        if geo.y() < screen.y():
            geo.moveTop(screen.y())
        widget.setGeometry(geo)
        widget.show()

Note that I specifically avoided any elif above. While we could safely assume that almost nobody would use a screen so small that wouldn't fit the popup, it's still better to formally consider the possibility anyway.
Finally, some further suggestions:

it makes little point to have two instance attributes for the hour/minute widgets, since they are always being shown separately and eventually destroyed (and then recreated again); a better approach would be to create them only when necessary, and eventually reuse them, possibly updating their value whenever the timeChanged signal of QTimeEdit is emitted;
while there's technically nothing wrong in using "callbacks", the signal/slot mechanism of Qt provides better modularity and separation of concerns; interestingly enough, you're using the term "emits" in your question, but you're not emitting anything; instead of using callbacks, use a custom signal and actually emit it when required;
QAbstractSpinBox based classes handle mouse events that are not handled by their inner lineEdit(), meaning that simply overriding mousePressEvent() based on the button is probably inconsistent, as the user may be clicking on the frame; consider checking the actual press position based on how the _checkOnArrow() function above was implemented, which is what editable combo boxes actually do;


First of all, thank you very much, I will have to read through your solution several times. For now: Regarding your feedback: QDesktopWidget: I was not aware that it is outdated. I will use QScreen. Regarding instance attributes: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you mean "why two classes instead of one" (I don't think that's what you meant, but just to be sure:) The classes are similar but too different for me for a "two-in-one" solution. ("double circle" 0-11 and 12-23 vs. 0-59 etc.) If you mean create & destroy objects: Even though I always reuse my forms (are passed generated to the

presenter), creating & destroying popups felt cleaner (so the objects are guaranteed to only occupy space as long as they are running instead of continuing to exist in the background) Because of callbacks vs signals/slots: I had actually implemented everything with signals/slots first (hence "emit" in the question). These made a lot more sense to me when I kept using objects. Since I started destroying and recreating them over and over again, I found callbacks made more sense. I learned programming with c++. I am currently trying to learn Python as well as a good coding style

Is reusing objects cleaner coding? It felt easier/cleaner to always redo the objects instead.

I changed the if in mousePressEvent to if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self._onArrow: and added else: super().mousePressEvent(event). I am unsure, if thats what you meant. Although your solution works and is significantly better than my approach, there is still one drawback: The left side of the button does not light up on mouseover.
Possibly related:
If you then move the mouse over from the button to the "Lineedit", the button remains lit.
If this is due to my implementation, please let me know. If it's a overlooked mistake/easy to fix, it would be great if you could fix it.

@AndreasM. Removing the popup would make more sense if it was intended to be completely temporary, but those widgets are expected to always be part of the time edit and it makes more sense to keep them once they've been created, in order to simplify their implementation. In fact, this is similar to the popup of QComboBox, and is also exactly what QDateTimeEdit does: the internal QCalendarWidget is always created, and the container is eventually created after calling setCalendarPopup(True), but if it's set to False afterwards it does not delete it. In this way you only need to "set up" »

@AndreasM. » everything just once, and it makes the usage of signals even more appropriate. Note that the fact that you're using Python doesn't change anything, as signals should always be preferred when dealing with QObjects even in C++: it's the expected usage, and signals are more flexible, other than safer. About the hover issue, you're right, I forgot to check if the mouse hovers the line edit, which may happen if the mouse is moved very fast. I'll check into it and eventually update the code as soon as I'll be able to.

Well i learned it about 20 years ago. So far i couldn't solve my "button stays lit, when i go from button to lineedit part of the widget" issue. I will keep trying so. Nevertheless if it is easy to fix, an update would be very much appreciated.

i was able to solve my issue with an eventfilter. If I wanted to upload my CustomTimeEditWidget with your code to my Github (which I would have to create first), would you be okay with that?

@AndreasM. Sorry for the late reply. The event filter approach is the correct one, I've updated my code (you can check its editing history for changes) and it should work as expected now. I didn't test it accurately (I actually edited it by mind) so let me know if you got any issues and I'll eventually check it more carefully ASAP. Eventually, consider suggesting edits by using the related link at the bottom of the post.
